# Preprocessing before terminating pthread

Tags: linux, pthreads

Is there a way through which pthread will know that a termination request has been raised and then it decides when and how to terminate.

Ex.

```
void * thread_func(void *arg) {
    ...
    if (is_termination_request_raised()) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "termination request" and how are you raising it?

Comment: "Termination request" can be using pthread_cancel or pthread_kill or any other way through which we can signal to pthread that termination request is generated. Now it is up to pthread when it wants to enquire that such request is generated and then terminate gracefully. How to raise such request is what I am looking for. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: If you're using `pthread_cancel()`, you can set the thread's cancellation type to deferred, and use `pthread_cleanup_push()`/`pthread_cleanup_pop()` to register functions to call when the thread is cancelled, but you can't ignore the cancellation. If you're using `pthread_kill()` to send a signal to a particular thread, that thread can install a signal handler to do whatever when it gets it.

Comment: @Shawn You might want to explain what you mean by "you can't ignore the cancellation". `pthread_setcancelstate()` with `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE` will cause the thread to not act on cancellation requests until it is set back to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE`.

Comment: @EOF if the thread can be cancelled and gets cancelled, there's no way that I know of for it to ignore the effect short of being deferred and never calling a function that is a cancellation point. Iirc changing the state after getting a cancel doesn't do it. Maybe if it's done before a cancellation point is hit?

Comment: @Shawn Cancellation type (DEFERRED/ASYNC) and cancellation state (ENABLE/DISABLE) are orthogonal. You can set type to ASYNC (meaning your thread is cancelable without regard to cancellation points) and yet still block the cancellation until it's convenient by using DISABLE. Later when you re-ENABLE, the cancellation will actually occur (doing any cleanup specified by `pthread_cleanup_push`). (See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcanceltype.3.html)